# Adding multiple values for db column with relationship

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have an interesting problem. I have a DB model with two tables:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    first_name = ....
    last_name = ....
    email = ....
    orders = db.relationship("Order")

class Order(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Orders'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'))
    order = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=False)
```

Now i have a form which has the "first_name", "last_name" etc. fields to populate the User class but i also have a textarea field for "orders".

When the form is submitted i am doing the following:

```
new_user = User(fist_name=form.first_name.data, last_name=....)
if form.orders.data:
    order = Order(order=form.orders.data)
    new_user.orders = [order]
    db.session.add(order)
db.session.add(new_user)
db.session.commit()
```

Now this works just fine but now i want to split the "orders" field by comma and add each one into the db for the same User. I tried:

```
new_user = User(fist_name=form.first_name.data, last_name=....)
if form.orders.data:
    separate_data = str(form.orders.data).split(',')
    for item in separate_data:
        item = item.lstrip()
        order = Order(order=item)
        new_user.orders = [order]
        db.session.add(order)
db.session.add(new_user)
db.session.commit()
```

The problem is that only the last Order has the user_id foreign key of the "new_user" the ones before have an empty row in the column.

The second thing i tried is creating a dictionary:

```
new_user = User(fist_name=form.first_name.data, last_name=....)
if form.orders.data:
    n = 0
    orders_dict = {}
    separate_data = str(form.orders.data).split(',')
    for item in separate_data:
        n += 1
        item = item.lstrip()
        orders_dict[f'order{n}'] = item
    for key in orders_dict:
        item = item.lstrip()
        key = Order(order=orders_dict[key])
        new_user.orders = [key]
        db.session.add(key)
db.session.add(new_user)
db.session.commit()
```

But that has the same issue as before. Only the last order is added with a value in the "user_id" column while the ones before it have an empty row.

I cant seem to figure this out so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is `new_lead`? Did you mean `new_user.orders.append(order)`?

Comment: new_lead.orders = [order] you're overwriting it so only the last one works (actually it does not work at all, the variable name is wrong)

Comment: @python_user Yes the new_lead is new_user thats my bad it used to be called lead now its called user but thats just my bad for misswriting it here its correctly written in the code. Edited the question to reflect this change.

Comment: did you try what I suggested?

Comment: `new_user.orders.append(order)` this is what I meant, instead of `new_user.orders = [order]`

Comment: @python_user yes i tried it and it works great. Please post it as an answer and ill select it.

Comment: posted the same as an answer with a bit of an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it, at every iteration of your loop you are replacing the relationship (it is a list) with a new list that has only one element `[order]`.

You have to instead append `order` at every iteration.

Using `new_user.orders.append(order)` instead of `new_user.orders = [order]` should give you what you want.